# Can we run a single litespeed license on two different ec2 ubuntu servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, litespeed

For the ec2 server from my aws account, I wanted to apply auto scaling policy such that if load increases on my one server, it should scale out to create another server and should scale in when the load decreases.
 But, the thing is that the my application for which I am going to apply auto scaling is running on lsws.
So, I am quite worrying about litespeed licensing. 
Does the single license serves both if in case two servers gets created due to load ? 
 
Does light speed have an option for licensing a server farm ?

Please, let me know if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 0):

If scaling CPU and RAM on the same server without changing server signature,  LSWS license should be ok, but one license cannot be used on two servers.

Comment: Hi @Jackson, thanks for an idea. But, is there any way from aws console or anything so that, we can do auto scaling the CPU and RAM on the same server in the particular situations only. Example, when the load increases and then scale down automatically when load decreases ?

Comment: Doesn't seem there is an easy way to add CPU and RAM to the same instance on AWS, or you maybe consult AWS expert.